# Function Call and variables problems

Tags: php, function

I would like to ask a question about php . That's related php function , there are two different function but whenever call this function , doesnt work below highlight(***Doesnt Work Area***) place .By the way , I tried call content variable from out of function and also I wrote global variable but I couldnt.

Do you know , why ?

```
Java () {

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE candidate_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
if(isset ($_POST['language'])) {
$deneme=$_POST['language']; 
}
$file= $userRow['candidate_name'];
touch($file.'.java');


if ( isset ($_POST ['content']) )     
{

file_put_contents ($file.'.java',$_POST ['content']); **Doesnt Work HERE!**

    }


exec("C:\Java\java\bin\javac -verbose $file.java 2>&1" , $output, $resultCode);
.
.  
.
.
.
.
}
```

Is there any advice about it ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you sure that `if ( isset ($_POST ['content']) )` is true?
2. Check write permissions
3. Execute after writing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Java () {
```

You should use:

```
function Java() {
    // Function contents...
}
```

Comment: I wrote function java but there is no on screen :( but didnt work